# How to display only the number of jobs running in HPC by specific user?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, slurm, high-performance

I want to Display only the number of jobs running in the HPC related to my username!
I don't wanna see all the jobs as the command **`squeue`** does!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Literally the first line of the Options description in `man squeue`:

> `-A <account_list>, --account=<account_list>`
> Specify the accounts of the jobs to view. Accepts a comma separated list of account names. This has no effect when listing job steps. #

Comment: What's the <account_list> stand for?

Comment: That is specified directly below. Please reread the full answer.

Comment: I actually did before asking the question!, but it doesn't work, that gives nothing in the output!  `squeue -A userx`

Comment: then that `userx` is not the right account.

Comment: How sir ! is my account !!

Comment: But it does not seem to be the account you are known under by squeue

Comment: for example ! `squeue -u userx` shows all the jobs with their IDs, and nodes ....., but I wanna check just how many jobs for this user x are running!